# Calling method from SOAP returns null

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap

i have C# Console App where i am going to connect soap service. I used many different type of soap services in this project with successfully. But last one, yesterday one another company send us a new SOAP service.

1. I connected using SOAP UI. Result is returning successfully.
2. I tried to add it to JAVA project created on NetBeans. It says:
   parsing WSDL...
   [ERROR] invalid extension element: "wsdlsoap:body" (in namespace  http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/")
3. Last i have tried, to connect it with C#. In Visual studio as usually i added service reference. Client created. But result is null;

I will give you more detail information about last section(section 3).

- I have successfully created ServiceClient
- I am calling it with such way:

  ```
  var client = new WebToCFTPortClient();
  var res = client.getXXXListByID(ref system, data);
  //res and system variables now is null
  ```
- So i added Behaviors to client's Endpoint to see what is sending and what is receiving. I see that sent correct XML, because i took it and pasted to SOAP UI and it gave normal result. And Received XML is correct to. 
  So as you see result as XML receiving correctly, but client can not parse it to class that came from imported service.

**UPDATE**
I tried other way. i am generating XML and send it to service with HttpWebRequest. And it is working. Yes it is hard to generate and then parse XML result to object. But i want to choose this way. What do you think?

Comment: Which behaviors did you add to the client's endpoint, and what did you see? Usually, if null is returned from all or part of a web service response, it indicates a disagreement about the XML namespaces to be used. It may also be an issue with the WSDL using the `element` vs `type` element in the `messages` section. `element` is non-compliant. Also, that JavaBeans error suggests that you did not really add the service reference "successfully".  Take a look at the generated code to see if it looks complete compared to the WSDL.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, i Behavior that implement IEndpointBehavior. And added IClientMessageInspector as  Message Inspector.

Comment: Just curious why you didn't just turn on message tracing?

Comment: @JohnSaunders, if we need for it, i can do it. Bu over clientMessageInspector i am still catching what is sending and what is receiving

Comment: It's just that turning on message tracing is trivial and requires no code.

Comment: Now that you have something working, please compare the XML that you send manually with the XML that was being sent by the Service Reference.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, It is same that i send via SOAP UI and via Service Reference